# Mimic right-click-key found on T420 keyboard

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey, thinkpad, context-menu, right-click

#### Background

I used to have an old Thinkpad (T420?). The keyboard had a *right click key* on the keyboard, shown below.

[image]

It was pretty convenient. I could open a folder, scroll down through the files in the folder using the arrow keys, and then click the *right click key* on the keyboard. Regardless of where the cursor was located, clicking the *right click key* would cause the right-click context menu to open for the file I had selected.

#### My solution

I recently got a T430. It does not have the *right click key* on the keyboard. After realizing that I used the *right click key* quite often, I decided to use an [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script to emulate the old *right click key*.

The script I used (in a `.ahk` file) was:

`PrintScreen:: Click Right`

It makes the `PrtSc` key right click. The `PrtSc` key on the T430 keyboard is located right where the *right click key* was on the T420, shown below.

[image]

#### The problem

However, this acts as if I clicked the right-click *mouse button*. So rather than it right-clicking on whatever file/folder/thing I have selected, it right-clicks where the cursor is located.

Is there a way to mimic the *right click key* found on the T420 keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the right click key, use the [`AppsKey`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#other) in AutoHotkey.

> This is the key that invokes the right-click context menu.

```
PrintScreen::send {AppsKey}
```